# Find time average time difference between stages

Tags: sql, sql-server

In `SQL Server 2012`, I have a database table called `Stages` that has 3 columns:

1. AccountID
2. StageNum
3. StartTime

I am trying to find out how long it usually takes between each stage. IE stage 2 usually takes 3 days to complete. Is this possible? Is it possible to skip weekends too?

Any SQL would be helpful!

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What does the table and data look like?

Comment: Use lag or lead functions to calculate time difference between each stage.

Comment: @L0uis the table is called Stages and has three columns: AccountID, StageNum, StartTime.

Comment: @AAA Add sample data and desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the use of LEAD and AVG as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab1(
  AccountID INT, StageNum INT, StartTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Tab1 VALUES(1, 1, '2018-01-01 07:00:00.000'), (1, 2, '2018-01-03 12:54:00.000'), (1, 3, '2018-02-01 12:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO Tab1 VALUES(2, 1, '2018-03-01 00:00:00.000'), (2, 2, '2018-04-03 12:54:00.000'), (2, 3, '2018-08-01 12:00:00.000')


WITH cte AS(
SELECT *
      ,LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY t.AccountID ORDER BY t.StageNum) NextStart
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY t.AccountID ORDER BY t.StageNum))/60.0 TimeSpanHours
  FROM Tab1 t
)
SELECT AccountID, AVG(TimeSpanHours) AvgTimeSpanHours
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY AccountID
  ORDER BY AccountID
```

Comment: This answer is much more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @AAA I just noticed I calculated AVG over AccountID - you can exchange it with StageNum in order to get the average per stage. However, wht it does NOT calculate is the timespan of Stage 3 - How is it defined? Are all AccountIDs sequentially and the next start of Stage 1 means the end of the previous stage 3? I will gladly expand my solution accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is:

```
select ( datediff(minute, min(StartTime), max(StartTime)) /
         nullif(60.0 * (count(*) - 1), 0)
       ) as avg_hours
from t;
```

The `nullif()` prevents division by zero.  The idea is simple . . . take the total amount of time and divide by one less than the number of stages.

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: Nice idea, but it does neither consider the "between each stage" nor per account nor nothing. Furthermore it produces a wrong result: taking the example data from my solution, your query produces something like -1018.6 hours as avg...

Comment: @Tyron78 . . . That was a small typo.  The start and end times were backwards.  The point is that you don't need to calculate the intermediate "between each stage" values to get the result you want.

Comment: But the desired result was "time per stage" ;-)

Comment: @Tyron78 . . . And this is a more efficient way to do the calculation.